# How to get store location of image uploaded from carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have a avatar uploader using carrierwave and I want to get the location image at store which in my case is AWS.

I have used after_save callback of active record but it is giving me cache location. My code to get image location is

```
avatar.thumb.url
```

example location that i am getting

> /uploads/tmp/1407250444-20636-7072/Score.png

I am using Rails4 and carrierwave version is 0.10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be:

```
/path/to/your/project/public/uploads
```

There will be a lot of folders of your models that contain uploaded imaages